# How to draw a 2d projection (circle) of a 3D object (sphere) in Mathematica?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, mathematica-8, mathematical-expressions

SphericalPlot3D[
 Cos[[Theta]], {[Theta], 0, [Pi]}, {[Phi], 0, 2 [Pi]}]
This gives me a sphere. But what should I do in order to get a projection of it along any of the plane, let say a-b plane? It should look like a circle. Any idea would be greatly acknowledged as I am quite new in Mathematica. Thanks!

N.B: for a-b plane, theta would be fixed ([Pi]/2)

Answer (score 0):

I think, I got it. I just have to plot using 'PolarPlot' for a fixed theta. This gives me the projection for a-b plane. For any general direction one can choose accordingly value of theta.